# Hide :before on :hover button

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

I am missing how I should hide the :before element, and only make it visible when it is "inside" the button div, to create a *filling* effect on the hover button.

```css
a.button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

a.button:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.button:hover {
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

a.button:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">buttt</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `:before` element height to `0` , then change it on `:hover:before` to `100%`

**The snippet**

```css
a.button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

a.button:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.button:hover {
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

a.button:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">buttt</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your link in a div and set overflow to hidden like this :

```css
    a.button {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #000;
      border: 2px solid #000;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
    }

    a.button:before {
      transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: red;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }
.wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 65px;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    a.button:hover {
      transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
      color: #fff;
    }

    a.button:hover:before {
      transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
      top: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap"><a href="#" class="button">buttt</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` and `overflow:hidden` to `a.button` styling, as default display of a tag is `inline`.

```css
a.button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block; /* Add this */
  overflow:hidden; /* Add this */
}
a.button:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.button:hover {
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

a.button:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">buttt</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only insert This:

```
a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  //Other Codes...
}
```

```css
a.button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a.button:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.button:hover {
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

a.button:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">buttt</a>
```